# Sending email CPanel

Tags: email, server, cpanel

the problem is this:

I need to send an email to a Google Apps account with the same domain that I have delegated to our server from CPanel.
The problem is that when I send an email from no-reply@mydomain.ie (email server) to support@mydomain.ie (gapps email) [same domain, different servers] not from the server, but it tries to find "support" on the local server and can not find (No Such User Here).
Is there any way from CPanel, so that if the user does not find email (support), send it the same? Considering that to send email no-reply@mydomain.ie have the account and use local data.

Thanks!
Alejandro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using Google Apps for email service. It seems that your mail exchanger is set to local in your cPanel.

Go to WHM -> Edit MX and edit this domain. Here you will get an option to set remote mail exchanger for your domain.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is the solution.
I added the Google MX Records and worked perfectly!